# Can a local domain have its field of fractions and residue field isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

$R$ is a local commutative integral domain that is not a field with maximal ideal $m$ and fraction field $F$. Is it possible that there is an isomorphism $R/m \cong F$?

Equivalently, is it possible that there is a surjection $R \rightarrow F$ or that there is an injection $R \rightarrow R/m$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F=\Bbb Q(X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ be the field generated over $\Bbb Q$ by an infinite
sequence of transcendental elements. Then $F\cong F(X)$. Now take $R$ to be
the localisation of the polynomial ring $F[X]$ at the prime ideal $(X)$.
The residue field is $F$ and the field of fractions is $F(X)$.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I wanted this to be impossible so bad i didn't think much about counterexamples.  turns out in my particular use case it didn't matter because the supposed isomorphism would have made the associated triangle commute.