# If local rings $R\subset S$ have the same residue field, does $S$ dominate $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Is this correct?

If local rings $R\subset S$ have the same residue field, then $S$ dominate $R$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is no.

Until we know that $S$ dominates $R$, the only meaningful interpretation of "$R$ and $S$ have the same residue field," as far as I can tell, is that $R$ and $S$ have isomorphic residue fields.

Let $k$ be any field and $F = k(x_1, x_2, \ldots )$ the field generated by a countably infinite number of algebraically independent elements.  Let $R = F[x_0]_P$, where $P$ is the maximal ideal of $R$ generated by $x_0$.  Then the residue field of $R$ is simply $F$.  Meanwhile the fraction field of $R$ is $F(x_0)$.  Note that the map from $F$ to $F(x_0)$ which sends $x_{i+1} \to x_i$ for $i \geq 0$ is an isomorphism.  Set $S = F(x_0)$.  Then $R \subseteq S$ is an inclusion of a local domain into a field which is not dominant (because $S$ is the field of fractions of $R$) and such that the residue field of $R$ is isomorphic to $S$.

I learned about this example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664408/can-a-local-domain-have-its-field-of-fractions-and-residue-field-isomorphic).

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I previously left a comment here which did not make sense in light of the definition of dominance - apologies if you happened to see it! I've since deleted it.